# Pandas get normalize using groupby and size and transform

Tags: pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'subset_product':['A','A','B','C','C','D'],
                   'success': [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
                   'count':[5,4,1,1,1,0]})
```

Above is dataframe.
success =1 means success and success = 0 mean failure..
count = number of such event.
Need to get success percent for each subset product.

expected output:

```
A   5/9
B   1
C   1/2
D   0
```

I am getting the count using below:

```
a = df.groupby('subset_product')['count'].transform('sum')
```

But, stuck here with count itself..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can add a helper column and compute the sums per group:

```
g = df.eval('x=success*count').groupby('subset_product')
out = g['x'].sum()/g['count'].sum()
```

output:

```
subset_product
A    0.555556
B    1.000000
C    0.500000
D         NaN
dtype: float64
```

###### alternative using `pivot_table`

```
d = df.pivot_table(index='subset_product', columns='success',
                   values='count', aggfunc='sum')
d[1]/d.sum(1)
```